# How to display alternative color in datagridview if it is empty?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The `Alternative BackColor` property works if there is data in datagridview . I want to show `Alternative BackColor`if it is empty.

Comment: how do you displays rows in datagridview if its empty???

Comment: Change Default and Alternative BackColors

Comment: @FerasSalim, I am not showing. I want to show datagridview alternative color.

Comment: @Fabio How?? Can you briefly explain

Comment: @Vampire see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txth0a6h.aspx

Answer (score -1):

When declaring your GridView, you can configure options in the `EmptyDataRowStyle` and the `EmptyDataRowStyle` elements. So I suppose you can assign the same value to the `BackColor` in both `EmptyDataRowStyle` and `AlternatingRowStyle` elements like in the sample below.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="myGridView">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No data</EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="Red" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Red" />
</asp:GridView>
```